# C error X is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'

Tags: c

I am learning some C, and I have the following code, basically want I would like to do is to increase the size of `people` array in the for loop, but currently I receive an error.
Could you please provide me a fix to my script with a brief explanation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person {
   int id;
};

struct State {
   struct Person people[0];
};

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");

    struct State state = {};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      struct Person person = {};
      person.id = i;
      state->people[i] = person;
    }
  
    return 0;
```

Error I receive:

```
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:19:12: error: member reference type 'struct State' is not
      a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
      state->people[i] = person;
      ~~~~~^~
           .
1 error generated.
exit status 1
```

Comment: Well the compiler is correct. The variable `state` isn't a pointer so you can't use the "arrow" operator.

Comment: You have another problem though, that's the *zero* sized array `people` in the `State` structure. Why is it zero-sized? What does your text-books, tutorials or classes say about arrays and their sizes?

Comment: Also please don't tag multiple programming languages, only the one you actually program in.

Comment: You got `person.id = i;`right, so why did you decide to use `->`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, given that you know what `->` is used for: it is used when the struct (its left operand) is a pointer. It's equivalent to `(*pointer_to_struct).`. It does not matter what type the right operand of `->` got.

You have no pointers to structs in your code so you can't use `->`.

Also `struct State state = {}` is invalid C, an initializer list cannot be empty. You need to set at least one element, so for example you can do `{0}` and that will set everything in the struct to zero/null.

Comment: thanks I changed using code below, but now I get a: signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");

    struct State state = {};
    struct State *myPointerState = &state;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      struct Person person = {};
      person.id = i;
      myPointerState->people[i] = person;
      printf("%s", myPointerState->people[i]);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would you be able to write a working snippet for me, so I can learn the right way thanks

Comment: @Radex `struct State *myPointerState` should be `struct Person* something = state.people;` In general, you can't program by trial & error, you need to actually understand what every line of code you are writing does.